# Migrating Old Windows XP and 7 machines to VMs to improve security

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtual-machine, security, virtualization

I work for a manufacturing company which has all kinds of equipment that runs older operating systems. Some have computers that run full blown Windows XP and Windows 7, while others run embedded Windows NT.

There are certain requirements for this older PCs that make it difficult to stomach leaving them on the shop floor. Currently our firewall is directly blocking traffic from their internal IPs out to the internet and vice versa.

I want to move these computers directly to modern operating systems but worry that they won't be compatible, and I know a few of them need the older operating systems to even run at all.

I want to explore moving these older machines to VMs but am not sure where to even begin, or what processes I can use to harden them.

Has anyone done this before or have any experience with this process?

Comment: They're 'safe' so long as they can never reach or be reached from the interwebz. Sitting them inside VMs means your backups can just be copies of the current state, in a simple 1, 2, 3 structure. There are many online guides to creating VMs of existing computers.

Comment: Get VCenter Converter from VMware and convert them with Converter. You will need to search for an old version or XP for sure and possibly for Windows 7.

Comment: Test it! it takes just minutes to set up a VM such as Oracle's VirtualBox, https://www.virtualbox.org/, a few minutes more to create a Windows XP or 7 VM on it... but, unfortunately, a bit longer to bypass the intrinsic "firewall" in the VM to connect to your device. It sounds like a good choice, so you no longer are dependent on maintaining additional, irreplaceable, 32-bit PC's.

Comment: I recommend VMware Workstation in a company environment instead of VBOX

Comment: I did exactly that for a small set of PC's, the main problem I stumbled upon was some of the systems required drivers that were not available in newer OS versions, (centinel keys, usb dongles, etc), the other less frequent problem was legacy software using system API , that was not working with newer OS or 32/64 bit mismatch.

Comment: Drivers are already in the migrated VM OS. The VM should have no clue it's not really running on 1999 hardware.

Comment: We did this using microsoft's disk2vhd to make a vhd image of a harddisk, then load that vhd either in oracle virtualbox or any other vm software that loads the vhd image.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to copy the OS to a VM.

I like using Clonezilla or drbl to setup a PXE boot.

1. create a new VM with appropriate RAM, and drive space slightly larger than the original.
2. Boot Clonezilla/drbl is server mode from a ISO attached to the VM
3. PXE boot the client and let clonezilla/drbl copy the data over.
4. When done reboot the VM and detach the ISO